# Shell script Variable Structure

Tags: linux, shell, unix, variables

How can I create a variable with a file name format like : 
FileName pattern: SnapshotIR__somenumber.csv

I tried something like :

```
TODAY=$(date +"%m%d%Y")    
SNAPSHOT = $(SnapshotIR$TODAY*.csv)
```

I get error like :

```
test.sh: line 2: SnapshotIR02122013_2239.csv: command not found
test.sh: line 2: SNAPSHOT: command not found
```

so, when I want to use with if

```
if [ -f SnapshotIR$TODAY*.csv]  -> works 
if [ -f ${SNAPSHOT} ]           -> does not work (I get the above error)
```

Comment: Get rid of the spaces around the `=`.

Comment: Thanks for that, but that dint help with the error.

Comment: That should fix `SNAPSHOT: command not found`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SNAPSHOT=SnapshotIR${TODAY}\*.csv
```

when you give $(.....) it says shell to execute the command within the braces.
i guess you are just forming the file name.

also remove the spaces:

```
SNAPSHOT<space>=<space>
```

i would also like to add wildcard "*" will not work for -f flag.

```
for file in $SNAPSHOT
do
        if [ -f "$file" ]
        then
                FOUND="$file"
                break
        fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I got rid of one error but I still get : test.sh: line 2: SNAPSHOT: command not found
Is that expected  ?

Comment: i don't have any space. This can be used like : if [ -f ${SNAPSHOT} ]    right ?